# VBA How to determine which row was selected in a Listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

How to determine, which row was selected in a `ListBox`? I'm asking here because, all I have found so far, requires to loop through all rows to check if was selected or not, but I was wondering if something simple exists, as I'm using mode `MultiSelect 0-fmMultiSelectSingle` only an integer is expected...

Comment: If you have multiselect off you can simply get the `listbox.value`. It's only when multiselect is on that you have to loop through.

Comment: Thanks that explanation was helpful!

Comment: `Listbox1.Value` will give you the value and `Listbox1.ListIndex + 1`  will give you the selected row. `If Listbox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then MsgBox "Selected row = " & Listbox1.ListIndex + 1 Else MsgBox "Nothing Selected"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you filled the list box using the `ListFillRange` property, or otherwise used a contiguous worksheet range, the 3rd item in the listbox will be from the row of the 3rd cell in the range.

```
R = Range(ListFillRange).Rows([Listindex]).Row
```

where *[Listindex]* is the ListIndex of the selected list box item.

If this easy way isn't available, f.i. because the list was created using a filter, the thing to do is to create a multicolumn list box with an extra, hidden, column and record the row number there at the time of list creation.

You would need to loop only if the items in the list box were not extracted from the worksheet in the first place, and this is the reason why doing so wouldn't be the best solution for creating the list box's list.